# How to change the position of a RadioButton's label?

Tags: java, css, javafx, radio-button, javafx-8

By default `RadioButton`s have their text label to the right of the button. I want the label to appear below the button instead. I found an [old discussion on the Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2433006) but the solutions aren't great or just don't work.

I can create a custom component with a text-less radio button and a separate text label and position them as in a `VBox`. But then only the button itself responds to user events and not the whole thing.

Is there no simple way to reposition the label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "simple" way to do this (simple means setting a single property or something like this).

As a workaround you could do something like you mentioned with a `VBox`, but with a `Label`: You can set the `RadioButton` as the graphic of the `Label` and set the [`contentDisplayProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty) to `TOP` (`RadioButton` is placed on top of the `Label`). And then you can add an event handler on the `Label` to select the `RadioButton` on click.

**An example with this approach**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.getChildren().add(createRadioLabel("Radio on the left", ContentDisplay.LEFT));
            hbox.getChildren().add(createRadioLabel("Radio on the top", ContentDisplay.TOP));
            hbox.getChildren().add(createRadioLabel("Radio on the bottom", ContentDisplay.BOTTOM));
            hbox.getChildren().add(createRadioLabel("Radio on the right", ContentDisplay.RIGHT));
            hbox.setSpacing(30);
            root.setCenter(hbox);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Label createRadioLabel(String text, ContentDisplay cd) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setGraphic(new RadioButton());
        label.setContentDisplay(cd);
        label.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) ((Label) e.getSource()).getGraphic();
            radioButton.requestFocus();
            radioButton.setSelected(!radioButton.isSelected());

        });
        return label;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*And the produced `RadioButton`s*:

[image]

Alternatively, **if you want to have the text of the `RadioButton` rotated around the dot**, you can use CSS rotations, with the attribute `-fx-rotate`:

```
.radio-button { -fx-rotate:180; }
.radio-button > .text { -fx-rotate: 180; }
```

The first selector will rotate the whole `RadioButton`, so as result the text will be placed on the left side of the "dot", upside down. The second selector rotates the text back to the normal direction.

**Example**

This example shows a `RadioButton` whose `Text` can be placed to any side of the "dot" specified by a `ComboBox` selection.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton("In all directions);

            ComboBox<PseudoClass> combo = new ComboBox<>();
            combo.getItems().addAll(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("left"), 
                    PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("top"),
                    PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("right"), 
                    PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("bottom"));

            combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {

                if (oldVal != null)
                    rb.pseudoClassStateChanged(oldVal, false);

                rb.pseudoClassStateChanged(newVal, true);
            });

            root.setTop(combo);
            root.setCenter(rb);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*application.css*

```
.radio-button:left > .text { -fx-rotate: 180; }
.radio-button:left { -fx-rotate:180; }

.radio-button:right > .text { -fx-rotate: 0; }
.radio-button:right { -fx-rotate:0; }

.radio-button:top > .text { -fx-rotate: 0; }
.radio-button:top { -fx-rotate:-90; }

.radio-button:bottom > .text { -fx-rotate: 0; }
.radio-button:bottom { -fx-rotate:90; }
```

*And the displayed `RadioButton`:*

[image]

Comment: Very complete answer and works. Thank you! I ended up creating a class from the code you gave in order to support a toggle group because a label doesn't and it needs to delegate it to its radio button.

Comment: (Unless you have a better way of supporting toggle groups with this)